# Root of a Monte Carlo integral

Tags: numerical-methods, monte-carlo

Given $y$, I wish to find $x$ (which lies in a known certain range) such that $F(x) - y = 0$, for some monotonically increasing $F$ which I can approximate at specific values of $x$ by Monte Carlo integration.
Currently I am just performing many evaluations over a grid.

Is there a nice algorithm to achieve this?  It feels like there should be some cunning way to, given the current sampled values, choose a new point to sample to increase our information about where the root lies.

Comment: Are you aware about the plenty of numerical algorithms about finding roots of an equation? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: @Crostul yes, but to my knowledge they require the exact evaluation of the function.  To Monte Carlo estimate the function to the precision required at each step would be expensive.  I want to go from sampling of $F$ to estimation of root.  Looking at the wikipedia page, all those methods would fail given noisy evaluations.